# Proving a property of a $L^1(\mu)$ function.

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I need to prove: $(\Bbb{X}, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space and let $f \in L^1(\mu)$.

Then, $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to \infty} \mu(\{ x : |f(x)| \gt t\}) = 0$

My thoughts: We proved in class that if $f \in L^+$ and $\int_{\Bbb{X}}f\ d\mu \lt \infty$ then $\mu(\{ x : f(x) = \infty\}) = 0$ and I think I have to incorporate it somehow into my proof. Am I on the right track?

Comment: yes , use the result that you ve proved by taking the $|f|$.

Comment: Yeah guessed that much (should've written it down). I just wondered if that's it... Is the question THAT simple.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You'd better use [this inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality).

Comment: yes you are right , now that am thinking about it you cant modify it and use the previous exercise , my fault  :(.

Answer (score 1):

Proving the above is equivalent to showing that -
$ \lim_{n\to\infty}  \mu  \{ x : |f(x)|>n \} =0$.

Define the set $ K_n = \{x \in X : |f(x)| \leq n\}$
Then, since $f \in L^1(\mu)$, we have that 
$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{K_n} |f| d\mu = \int_{X} |f|d\mu$ by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem.
Hence, the above equation becomes, 
$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{{K_n}^c} |f| d\mu= 0$
Since, $ 0\leq n\mu(K_n)^c \leq \int_{{K_n}^c} |f|d\mu$
Hence taking limits on both sides and by the the Sandwich theorem, we get the required result.